# Set tooltip for an editor

Tags: smartgwt

I have the following code snippet for creating an input field for entering colors:

```
DataSourceTextField colorField = 
    new DataSourceTextField(ZoneDto.ATTR_COLOR, "*localized name*", 7, true);
colorField.setEditorType(new ColorPickerItem());
colorField.setPrompt("*localized instructions*");
```

This works quite well, since the input field has the localized instructions in its tooltip, but the small square that opens the color picker window has the original english tooltip ("Click to select a new color").

How could I change this message to a localized one?

Is this even possible to accomplish? I read that setEditorType only sets a template, from which instances are generated whenever needed. This means it's not going to work if I add setPrompt("*localized instructions*") to the ColorPickerItem given to the setEditorType().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, why not fill a variable 'localizedStringForColorPicker' with the current selected localization upon startup. And change it, when another localization is selected?

Comment: My problem is not with changing localizations, this application would only be used in hungarian. All other native localized SmartGWT strings work just fine (using the default GWT localization system), but this one seems to be hardwired to the ColorPickerItem and I see no methods for changing or even overriding it.

Comment: Have you tried to use "redraw()" just after you change the String?

Comment: This all takes place in the constructor of a DataSource (before it is injected into the View component of the app), so there is no drawing going on during these lines.

Comment: I just wonder if you could instanciate the color picker first, thus setting its prompt and then feeding its reference to the setEditorType method?